# generate differentiable colors similar to one color

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

lets say I have a web app and I need to show some text with different color that are obvious by eyes but all similar to for example red for example one pink and another dark red and ...

I use server side and in my servlet I remove the last 3 part of my color FF0000 and add for example 100

the code is as follow

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
  "FF0000".subSring(0,6-3)+i*100
}
```

but the problem is that all colors are kind of the same and noone can differentiate them

How can I solve this?(also I am ok with jquery solution as well)

Comment: consider using HSL color instead of RGB, you can find some code converting between the 2 yourself.

Comment: Can you explain more?( I have my color code like this #FF0000 and I want other colors around this)?

Comment: the HSL color has 3 components called Hue, Saturation and Lightness. You can modify those components easily to get some close colors, which is harder to do by modifying the 3 components RED, GREEN, BLUE in the RGB space. After getting the desired colors, you can convert them back to RGB colors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my suggestion:

- Retrieve the RGB values by using jQuery CSS of a DOM element.
- Convert it to HSL values.
- Play with the Lightness value (0,1) for color variation (of the same color).

**DEMO**:[JSnippet Demo](https://www.jsnippet.net/snippet/306/Color-variation-script)

Here are the main function I use (Conversion functions are in the demo):

```
/**
* Gets any CSS color value and returns an array of variation
* With objects that holds the variations rgb values.
*
* @param   String  cssColor  The CSS color
* @param   Number  vars      How Many variation
* @return  Array             Array of objects - first is the original rgb.
*/

function getColorReturnVar(cssColor, vars) {
    results_rgb = [];
    results_hsl = [];
    inc = 0;
    $test = $("<div />").css({ 
       background:cssColor, 
       width:'1px', 
       height:'1px' 
    });
    $('body').append($test);
    rgb = $test.css('backgroundColor');
    $test.remove();
    rgb = rgb.replace(/rgb\(|rgba\(| |\).*/gi,"").split(',');
    results_rgb[0] = {r:parseInt(rgb[0]),g:parseInt(rgb[1]),b:parseInt(rgb[2])};
    results_hsl[0] = rgbToHsl(results_rgb[0].r, results_rgb[0].g, results_rgb[0].b);
    if (results_hsl[0].l < 0.5) 
       inc = Math.floor(((1-results_hsl[0].l)/(vars+3)) * 100) / 100;
    else 
       inc = (Math.floor(((results_hsl[0].l-0)/(vars+3)) * 100) / 100)*-1;
    for (var i=1; i< vars+1; i++) {
        results_hsl[i] = { h:results_hsl[i-1].h,s:results_hsl[i-1].s,l:results_hsl[i-1].l + inc };
        results_rgb[i] = hslToRgb(results_hsl[i].h,results_hsl[i].s,results_hsl[i].l);
    }
    return results_rgb;
}
```